Munkres Topology Lemma 13.2: Confusion on Validity of Proof
Lemma 13.2 in Munkres' Topology states:

Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of open sets of $X$ such that for each open set $U$ of $X$ and each $x \in U$, there is an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x \in C \subset U$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for the topology of $X$.

And here's part of the proof, which proves that $\mathcal{C}$ indeed generates a topology.

We must show that $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis. The first condition for a basis is easy; Given $x \in X$, since $X$ is itself an open set, there is by hypothesis an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x \in C \subset X$. To check the second contition, let $x$ belong to $C_1 \cap C_2$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are elements of $\mathcal{C}$. Since $C_1$ and $C_2$ are open, so is $C_1 \cap C_2$. Therefore, there exists by hypothesis an element $C_3$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x \in C_3 \subset C_1 \cap C_2$.

Here I am confused about the boldfaced part of the proof. Why is it guaranteed that every $x$ can belong to two distinct elements of $\mathcal{C}$? In fact I think it is not guaranteed, since I think there is a counterexample for this: Think of the trivial topology of $X$. Then, only $X$ can be a possible element of $\mathcal{C}$.

Where does it claim that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are distinct?

Oh... It doesn't. So when $C_1 = C_2$ the rest of the proof is obvious, and whenever $C_1 \neq C_2$ we still can find a $C_3$ that is in $C_1 \cap C_2$. Did I understand it correctly?

Yes, that’s right


... let $x$ belong to $C_1 \cap C_2$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are elements of $\mathcal{C}$. ...
Why is it guaranteed that every $x$ can belong to two distinct elements of $\mathcal{C}$?

It is of course not guaranteed that each $x \in X$ is contained in the intersection of two members of $\mathcal{C}$. But this is not required. Munkres's second condition for a basis says

If $x$ belongs to $C_1 \cap C_2$, where $C_1, C_2 \in \mathcal{C}$, then there exists $C_3 \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x \in C_3 \subset C_1 \cap C_2$.

This is a logical implication which has to be satisfied for all  $C_1, C_2 \in \mathcal{C}$ and all $x \in C_1 \cap C_2$. Thus, if $C_1 \cap C_2 = \emptyset$, then there does not exist $x \in C_1 \cap C_2$ and the implication is vacuously satisfied.
More formally condition (2) says

$\forall C_1, C_2 \in \mathcal{C} \forall x \in X : [x \in C_1 \cap C_2 \implies \exists C_3 \in \mathcal{C} : x \in C_3 \subset C_1 \cap C_2]$


Update: (I managed to get hold of a copy of Munkres' book, so I've modified the answer to fit more closely with his presentation.)
The first examples of topological spaces one usually meet are metric spaces, where if $(X,d)$ is a metric spaces, the topology associated to the metric $d$ is given by declaring a subset $U$ of $X$ to be open if, for every $x\in U$, there is an open ball $B(x,r)= 
\{y \in X: d(x,y)<r\}$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq U$.
The notion of a basis for a topology seeks to generalize this in the following way: for a set $Z$, a collection of subsets of $Z$ is said to be a basis of a topology for $Z$ if
$$
\tau(\mathcal B) = \{U \subseteq X: \forall x \in U, \exists B\in \mathcal B \text{ such that } x\in B\subseteq U\}
$$
is a topology. Now a collection $\tau$ of subsets of a set $X$ is a topology if it is closed under unions and finite intersections. In order to see what this requires of the collection $\mathcal B$, lets suppose that $\tau$ is indeed a topology on $X$. Then since $X$ itself is always an open set, we see that:
$i)$: for every $x\in X$, there is some $B\in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in B$.
Now the open sets of a topology are closed under unions and finite intersections. The property that $\tau(\mathcal B)$ is closed under unions is immediate from the definition of $\tau(\mathcal B)$ for \emph{any} collection of subsets of $X$. On the other hand, if $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal B$ then they are themselves in $\tau(\mathcal B)$, and hence $B_1\cap B_2$ must be in $\tau(\mathcal B)$ if it is a topology. Spelling this out in detail gives:
$ii)$: if $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal B$, then for any $x \in B_1\cap B_2$ there is a subset $B_x \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in B_x\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.
Claim: If $Z$ is a set and $\mathcal B$ is a collection of subsets of $Z$ then $\tau(\mathcal B)$ is a topology if and only if $\mathcal B$ satisfies $i)$ and $ii)$.
The discussion above shows that if $\tau(\mathcal B)$ is a topology, then properties $i)$ and $ii)$ hold. The proof quoted in the OP gives the argument that if $\tau(\mathcal B)$ is a topology then property $ii)$ holds. Note this does \emph{not} require each $x\in Z$ to lie in an intersection $B_1\cap B_2$ for $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal B$. That said,  it is the case that every $x\in Z$ lies in such an intersection, since this follows from $i)$ -- given $x\in Z$, by $i)$ there is a $B \in \mathcal B$ with $x \in B$ and hence we may take $B_1=B_2 =B$.
